# Mono for Android performance comparing to Java

Tags: c#, java, performance, xamarin.android

I already read some bunch of articles, blogs and stackoverflow question about it but I ask it again for I am confused about a thing.

MonoDroid was a project before Xamarin show up and of course before Xamarin makes the XoboxOS Research Project. So many of those blogs that say MonoDroid is slightly slower and eats more battery for it has two frameworks running and two garbage collectors may target MonoDroid and not Mono for Android.

Benchmarks show that XobotOS is much faster than Dalvik so my question is:
Is apps written with Mono for Android still use both Dalvik VM and Mono VM? or they just run on the Mono VM which is faster than Dalvik VM? and which one eats more energy (Mono for Android or Java)?

I am currently working on a project which is about 50,000 line of code written in Java. I want to port it to iOS, Android, Windows 8 (Metro), Windows, WP, Mac OS X, Linux, etc. so it covers most popular operating systems of the world and for some of them I need to convert my code to another language. I first decided to convert to C#. Conversion is not a difficult thing for me for C# and Java are so similar but Instead I can use it everywhere. But I care about power consumption and performance so much. I do not care about file size that much though.

Thanks,

Comment: you might consider waiting a few more weeks. Oracle is open sourcing its Java implementation on Android and iOS.

Comment: Well, that's really cool! I really consider for my own use but since it's output for interface is HTML5 I highly doubt that it is faster than Obj-C/MonoTouch or even more efficient in case of power consumption.

Comment: `Mono is running side-by-side with the Dalvik`: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/architecture. On the other hand, Codename One provides a way to do cross platform development in Java: http://www.codenameone.com/.

Comment: It will be Java with AOT compilation to native code.

Comment: hmmmm, so it's pretty much like MonoTouch. that's interesting!